# Prove this problem with area

Tags: combinatorial-geometry

> Find all $n$ for which there exists an $n$-regular-polygon with all vertices on a lattice.

$4$ is the only answer (square) and can possibly prove by area.

By Pick’s theorem the area of any polygon with all vertices on a lattice $\in\mathbb Q$. Now we want to show that such an $n$-regular-polygon has an area $\not\in\mathbb Q$.

Let half of its side length be $x$ then its area $S=\dfrac{x^2n}{\tan\frac\pi n}$. This can be obtained by dividing the polygon into $n$ isosceles. Let one of its sides be $(x_1,y_1)(x_2,y_2)$ so $x^2=(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2\in\mathbb Q$. Therefore, $S\not\in\mathbb Q\Longleftrightarrow \tan\dfrac\pi n\not\in\mathbb Q$. Can we prove this?

Comment: A lattice polygon is not necessarily a polygon on the *square* lattice - there are answers other than $4$.

Comment: @RavenclawPrefect There aren’t. This is a theorem (only that it has no name. I suppose I didn’t use the terms correctly. I’ll change it in a minute.

Comment: You mean that there are no such polygons in the *integer* lattice: http://jdh.hamkins.org/no-regular-polygons-in-the-hexagonal-lattice/

Comment: Also, your proof relies on a variation of [Niven's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven%27s_theorem).